# form submit in codeigniter using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Here when I submit my form and will check validation in js file and then that will call the kickerLogin() function 
Got alert message of `datastring`, then this is not send to my url which is mentioned in ajax  but that will submit..........

```
function kickerLogin(){
    alert('hello friends');
    dataString=$('form[name=kickerLog]').serialize();
    alert(dataString);
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"<?php echo $GLOBALS['base_url']; ?>ajax/user-ajax.php?mode=kickerLogin",
        cache: false,
        data: dataString,
        dataType: "json",

        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
                if(data.success == "yes")
                {   
                    $('#kickerLog').submit();   
                }
                else if(data.success == "no")
                { 
                    if(data.status=="emailfail"){
                    $('li.log_error').show();
                     $('li.log_error').html("Email id not verified");
                    } 
                    else if(data.status=="rejected"){
                        alert("Your account is inactive by admin");
                    } 

                 else{  
                     $('li.log_error').show();
                     $('li.log_error').html("Invalid Email / Password");
                     $("#loginEmail").css("border","1px solid red");        
                     $("#loginPassword").css("border","1px solid red");    
                 }
                }

                else {
                    alert(" Occured internal Error.please check network connection" );
                }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: How is called kickerLogin() ? Attached to an event ?

Comment: Any errors in console??

Comment: check directly by hiting your ajax url in browser and check whether your controller function is called or not

Comment: Are you getting any error in console? if yes, paste it here.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `<?php echo $GLOBALS['base_url']; ?>` in your js file. Include this in your view may work then. Instead of `<?php echo $GLOBALS['base_url']; ?>` use `<?=base_url()?>` in your view.

Answer (score 0):

If your js function `kickerLogin()` is in a js file you can't use '',

Pass your url as one parameter while calling `kickerLogin()` function

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to call external files in CI.

```
//Instead of this
 url:"<?php echo $GLOBALS['base_url']; ?>ajax/user-ajax.php?mode=kickerLogin",

//Use this
//Where ajax is a controller ajax.php user_ajax is a function in it.
 url:"<?php echo site_url();?>/ajax/user_ajax?mode=kickerLogin",

//ajax.php controller
function user_ajax(){
$data['mode'] = $this->input->get('mode');
//Here load the file
$this->load->view('user-ajax');
}
```